# How to change the text in summary order (Prestashop 1.6.1.17)?

Tags: text, prestashop, customization, summary

Bonjour,

I build a website based on Prestashop 1.6.1.17. I encounter an issue that I wasn't able to resolve after hours of research. I looked in my default theme, in many plugins and in translation backoffice, in vain.

My specific problem : it is that I'd like to change the text circled in red in the summary order. Here is the capture that shows the problem :
[image: http://terrepourtous.free.fr/Issue2.jpg]

Test : you can test this issue by putting anything in your cart directly on [the website](http://la-maison-des-enfants.fr/), then you can see this order summary page.

Details to highlight exactly what I need : I'd like to replace **"Total produits ()"** by **"Total produits"** (without **"()"**).

How can I change this text in summary order ?

Thanks !

Comment: Edit your shopping-cart.tpl template in your theme folder. Look for line with `class="hookDisplayProductPriceBlock-price"` and delete it including the parentheses.

Comment: Roman K., you are amazing !

I deleted 2 full lines containing class="hookDisplayProductPriceBlock-price" and it totally worked !!!!

Thank you so much !!

Comment: @Pulpo, I'm glad it helped. I also added it as an answer so you can now accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your shopping-cart.tpl template in your theme folder. Look for line with `class="hookDisplayProductPriceBlock-price"` and delete it including the parentheses.